# Non-exhaustive functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wrote a function in Haskell:

```
recognize :: [GrammarRule] -> State -> [String] -> Bool
recognize [] x [s] = False
recognize gr x [s] = if elem True (map (\state -> elem state (takeSteps gr x [s]))(enders gr)) then True else False
```

this is non-exhaustive. What's the problem with the recognize function?
Thanks a lot!!

```
--the function takesteps is here: 
takeSteps :: [GrammarRule] -> State -> [String] -> [State]
takeSteps g s []     = [s]
takeSteps g s (w:ws) = concatMap (\nextState -> takeSteps g nextState ws) (successors g s w)

--the function enders is here:
enders :: [GrammarRule] -> [State]
enders [] = []
enders (r:rs) =
    let resultFromRest = enders rs in
    case r of
    End x -> x : resultFromRest
    Step x w' y -> resultFromRest
```

Comment: Avoid `if x then True else False`, it redundant. Just use `x`. Also turn on warnings with `-Wall` to catch these errors early.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[s]` matches a list with only one element, `s`.

If you want to match any list, use a simple identifier, `l` for example:

```
recognize [] x [s] = False
recognize gr x l = if elem True (map (\state -> elem state (takeSteps gr x l))(enders gr)) then True else False
                                               -- note the usage of l here ^
```